# How to sort column by HQL if column have both string and integer values

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, hql

I have a column "event_number" in "event" table. "event_number" column is actually varchar column in mysql.

I want to sort data according to "event_number" using HQL query. (Hibernate).

For example data is

```
event_number
1
2
M-2
4
5
K-C
6
7
8
9
10
11
TY-C
```

**The output should be:**

```
event_number
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
K-C
M-2
TY-C
```

or
**The output should be:**

```
event_number
K-C
M-2
TY-C
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

I have used HQL query:

```
select 
    event.eventNumber 
from 
    event 
order by 
    event.eventNumber asc;
```

I got result:

```
event_number
1
10
11
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
K-C
M-2
TY-C
```

Comment: I am sure but u can use `select cast(event.eventNumber as integer) from event order by event.eventNumber asc;`

Comment: Suganthan, i have used this HQL provided by you. It only sort numbers and replace all string with 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
select
    event.eventNumber
from
    event
order by
    cast(event.eventNumber as integer), event.eventNumber asc
```

The "cast(event.eventNumber as integer)" only sort the integers values.

The "cast(event.eventNumber as integer), event.eventNumber asc" sort both integer and string values

Comment: No works if the column return string and number at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
select cast(event.eventNumber as integer) from event order by event.eventNumber asc;
```

Comment: @Ishwar Lal let me try